# How can I do Select like this

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

```
    Declare @Result as varchar(max)='';
SELECT DISTINCT @Result =  dbo.MaterialTypes.Title + ', '+ @Result
FROM         dbo.TempId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.ProductMaterials ON dbo.ProductMaterials.Product = dbo.TempId.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.MaterialTypes ON dbo.ProductMaterials.MaterialType = dbo.MaterialTypes.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.Products ON dbo.Products.Id = dbo.TempId.Id
WHERE     (dbo.Products.IsCollection = 1)



SELECT DISTINCT dbo.TempId.Id AS MaterialCollection_id, @Result
FROM         dbo.TempId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.ProductMaterials ON dbo.ProductMaterials.Product = dbo.TempId.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.MaterialTypes ON dbo.ProductMaterials.MaterialType = dbo.MaterialTypes.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.Products ON dbo.Products.Id = dbo.TempId.Id
WHERE     (dbo.Products.IsCollection = 1)
```

this query is work, but i can't create View, based on this query. Please help!

Comment: then create a stored procedure and use wherever u need. May be u have declared a variable, in view therefore it is not working. I m not sure for this.

Comment: Yes i using MS SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As murtaza says you can create a **Stored Procedure** for this, or if you want to use this as a view you can create a **Table-valued Function** which you can use other views and joins.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165.aspx